# VBA to verify if text exists in a textbox, then check if date is in the correct format

Tags: forms, excel, vba, date, textbox

I have an excel form that I created in combination with VBA. In the form I have a textbox in which the user is to type in a date.

I have created this VBA clause to ensure the user types in a date that supports the format **xx/xx/xxxx.**

```
If Not IsDate(textboxDate1.Text) Then
  Call MsgBox("Please select a correct Date format", vbOKOnly)
  Exit Sub
End If
```

However, with this VBA code, the user is required to enter a date, whether the user needs to or not. So when I have a 4 other textboxes to input a date in my form, and the user only needs to enter in 1 date, and not 5, I have the problem where the user is required to put in a date for the other four textboxs in order submit the form.

So my question:
What VBA code is available to **first** determine whether text exists in the textbox, and then **second** to determine whether the date is in the correct format or not.

I was trying something similar to this:

```
 If textboxDate1.ListIndex = -1 Then
```

but I couldn't get it to work with the IsDate clause.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
If (Len(Trim(textboxDate1.Text)) <> 0)  And Not IsDate(textboxDate1.Text) Then 
  Call MsgBox("Please select a correct Date format", vbOKOnly) 
  Exit Sub 
End If
```

Comment: + 1 :) However a suggestion. You might want to use `Len(Trim(textboxDate1.Text)) <> 0` instead of `textboxDate1.Text <> ""`

Comment: +1 however, you can optimize this by checking length first. If `Len = 0` there is no point in checking `IsDate`.